# Validate numeric characters only Java

Tags: java, regex

I was wondering if there was a way to validate in my app so text entered into a "Phone Number" section can only add numeric characters and adds a System.out.println if the user attempts to enter Alphabetical/Special characters.
I've uploaded my code here: http://pastebin.com/jZ7Xgiq9
Since I'm not too sure how I'd implament it.

I was also wondering if there was a way to disable spaces being added?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Googles lib for parsing phonenumbers](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/), it's really neat!

Answer (score 0):

You can user [`NumberUtils.isDigits`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isDigits%28java.lang.String%29) from Apache

Comment: Why to use Apache library???? (Not me who downvoted)

Comment: @asifsid88 It will provide you with a well tested code that a regex may not be able to provide.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions. `[0-9]*`

Answer (score 0):

Add a KeyListener to txtPhone and use, 
                txtPhone.getText().matches("[0-9]*"); 
at keyTyped() event.